# How can I set the brown color using ANSI escape sequence?

Tags: c, linux, sequence, ansi-escape

Can I use only the sequence `Esc[Value,Valuem` to set the brown color of background? (not only Black,   Red,    Green,  Yellow,     Blue,   Magenta,    Cyan,   White... I want use more colors).

How to implement it easily? I want to implement it in my boot code, so I haven't the opportunity to use standard libraries.

Which parameters should I use?

Comment: A quick search led me to [this konsole (KDE terminal emulator) issue](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107487) where the first comment says how to use xterm escapes for up to 256 colors. Have you tried those codes?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks! I did't know about it. So i'll test it now.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI defined only 8 colors.  None are *brown* (though some people call the non-bright "yellow" a "brown", e.g., [Yellow appears as brown in konsole](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192660/yellow-appears-as-brown-in-konsole)).

If you want to use different colors in your Linux *boot code*, you could use the Linux console color palette escape sequence to alter one of the entries in the console's palette.  Referring to [console_codes(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) manual page:

```
   ESC ]     OSC      (Should be: Operating system command) ESC ] P
                      nrrggbb: set palette, with parameter given in 7
                      hexadecimal digits after the final P :-(.  Here n
                      is the color (0-15), and rrggbb indicates the
                      red/green/blue values (0-255).  ESC ] R: reset
                      palette
```

Some people have written programs (or scripts) using this feature, e.g., [setcolors - Change your Linux VT color palette (at boot time too!)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168392).

To alter colors in terminal emulators, e.g., after booting and logging into your desktop, these other terminals may have control sequences for setting entries in their color palettes.